# Save bytes in a .txt and read out as bytes later

Tags: python

I have written a small python script which encrypts a message with rsa.
Now I want to save the bytes in a txt to read them later.
But when I use str(...) on it I don't know how to convert the string back.

For example I encrypted "Test" to b'Y\xf8\xbc\xca\x14\x0f\x80\xd3\xc6\xce\xecE\x14\xc1\xaf\xbd\x82\xd24\xcf\x04\xe2\x9a\x81NF\xbeXi\x85\xef\xc4\xbbl\xd3(5\x80\xe4\xde3\x8eC\xd2jR*\xb7.gq\x8c\x8b\xa12\x1a\x10+\xbf\xefHZ\n/'
and saved it as a string.
When I aply bytes(...) on it I get the Error: TypeError: string argument without an encoding.

What can I do in order to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've saved the Python string `repr`esentation of a binary byte array (bytestring).

To get the actual bytes back from such a representation, pass it through `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = r"b'Y\xf8\xbc\xca\x14\x0f\x80\xd3\xc6\xce\xecE\x14\xc1\xaf\xbd\x82\xd24\xcf\x04\xe2\x9a\x81NF\xbeXi\x85\xef\xc4\xbbl\xd3(5\x80\xe4\xde3\x8eC\xd2jR*\xb7.gq\x8c\x8b\xa12\x1a\x10+\xbf\xefHZ\n/'"
>>> b = ast.literal_eval(s)
b'Y\xf8\xbc\xca\x14\x0f\x80\xd3\xc6\xce\xecE\x14\xc1\xaf\xbd\x82\xd24\xcf\x04\xe2\x9a\x81NF\xbeXi\x85\xef\xc4\xbbl\xd3(5\x80\xe4\xde3\x8eC\xd2jR*\xb7.gq\x8c\x8b\xa12\x1a\x10+\xbf\xefHZ\n/'
```

Better yet, just save the binary bytes to your file without passing through a string:

```
encrypted_bytes = my_rsa("Test")
with open("encrypted.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(encrypted_bytes)

# ...

with open("encrypted.bin", "rb") as f:
    encrypted_bytes = f.read()
```

If you really want a "text-safe" format for those bytes, use `base64.b64encode()` and `base64.b64decode()`.

Comment: So, I tried the last one with wb and rb.
But when I read the bytes in the file with 
with open(f"Accounts\{self.user}.txt", "rb") as file:
            lines = file.readlines()

I wrote b'\x936\xde9\xdf\x18\xd1t\xf7\r\xac\xb9\xf4\xfc\x8f\x0cn3\xb5C)\xe7u}\x15w\xca\xb8\x06\xdc\xd0\xd6\t\xc9\x0e\x9ce\x19\xcb4\x17\xa9[9[\xe9\x14R~\xb9\xb3\x05\x03~"~8\x1dB\xd8\xdbw:\xdd'  
but I got  
b'\x90f\xce\xd5\xd9\x84\x11\xeb\xc6r#f\xcc\xf4"\xd1g\xd2\x81u\xe0b(5iz\xcb\x0e\xe2\xbf\xc4\xc5q\xdc\x94\x98\xe4\xcb\x88g\xef\xa9\x8d?!\xd8\x86q\xe0\xa4\xe1\xbb\xdb\x1cd|$\x02+\xf2S\x9b\xb0\xc1\r\n'

Comment: You shouldn't use `readlines()` on a binary file. Use `.read()` to just read all of it.

Comment: Oh okay
But what do I do when I write multiple encrypted_bytes in the file and want to decrypt them seperately?

Comment: Then you'd need to come up with an encapsulation or delimiting scheme for the encrypted messages, e.g. trail each one with something that's impossible (or very, very highly unlikely) to appear in a real message, such as `======================`. You could then split the read bytes by that trailer, and you'd have your separate messages.

Comment: (Another scheme that would work better with large files could be to prefix each message with its length (as a `struct.pack()`ed integer), read in that many bytes for the message, and rinse and repeat until there's nothing left to read. This is basically a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93length%E2%80%93value scheme without the Type field.)

Comment: (And, of course, a third easy one would be to use the aforementioned `base64.b64encode()` function to encode the binary bytes into a text string, and store those as separate lines, then decode them back to binary before decrypting.)

Comment: Yeah thanks, I now used just an encapsulation for it and it also works to distinguish between the bytes and the other data stored in the file. Probably I'll try the base64 one also, but the other one wirks just fine